# R' Avigdor Miller quote

Tags: sources-mekorot, avigdor-miller

If anyone here has read Rabbi Avigdor Miller's Q and A's or heard any of his quotes or read them, can you help me find this that I remember reading/seeing.  He said that if a man has a day off work or something, he should go to the beis midrash and learn there and not come home until 10 pm.   Has anyone else heard/seen this?   Thanks.

Comment: Note that as with most non-halakhic advice, this is subject to variability based on individual circumstances. It is important to have a rabbi who can advise you personally regarding what seems best for you.

Comment: Found it.  It's question 279 in R' Tikotzky's q and a's, the "10 o'clock" is heard in the actual tape, it's just not in the transcription

Answer (score 5):

A Q&A from the archives
Question # 279

QUESTION:

How can you make your work incidental (despite working eight hours a day) and your learning should be the main part of your life?

... If you don't work on Sundays, be a kollel man on Sundays. "Oh!" your wife will say, "at least one day a week you have to be home!" Answer is, say, "My dear, I am not in the Yeshiva now, Yeshiva people are going full speed ahead every day of the week, I have one day and that one day I should waste?" So Sunday morning say good bye to your family, take along lunch and you spend the day someplace else, don't go home until nighttime.